# Javascript restrict input once 2 decimal places have been reached

Tags: javascript, decimal-point

I currently have a number input script that behaves similar to a calculator with the way numbers are displayed, but I want to stop the adding of additional numbers to the series after two numbers past the decimal point.

Here is what I have so far, though the limiting doesn't occur correctly.

It should work like this:

1.25 - Allowed

12.5 - Allowed

125.5 - Allowed

125.55 - Allowed

123.555 - Not Allowed

```
rText = document.getElementById("resultText");

function selectNumber(num) {
if (!rText.value || rText.value == "0") {
    rText.value = num;
}
else {
```

this part works...

```
        rText.value += num;

    }
  }
}
```

but this part doesn't work... Any ideas???

```
if (rText.value.length - (rText.value.indexOf(".") + 1) > 2) {

        return false;
    } else {
        rText.value += num;

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```js
var validate = function(e) {
  var t = e.value;
  e.value = t.indexOf(".") >= 0 ? t.slice(0, t.indexOf(".") + 3) : t;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="resultText" oninput="validate(this)" />
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great solution. Since substr is deprecated, here is a slice version: `e.value = t.indexOf(".") >= 0 ? t.slice(0, t.indexOf(".") + 3) : t;`

Answer (score 4):

Save the previous value in some data attribute and if it exceeds 2 decimal places then restore the previous value

The 2 decimal places can be checked using `Math.round(tis.value*100)/100!=tis.value`

## Note:

I have used `oninput`to validate even in copy paste scenarios

```js
function restrict(tis) {
  var prev = tis.getAttribute("data-prev");
  prev = (prev != '') ? prev : '';
  if (Math.round(tis.value*100)/100!=tis.value)
  tis.value=prev;
  tis.setAttribute("data-prev",tis.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="rText" oninput="restrict(this);" />
```

Comment: do you know how I an adapt this for a react component? using "this", typescript complains about "he containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'."

Answer (score 0):

I love to use Math.floor and toFixed() to resolve my decimal issues.

Here is a example:

```
var value = 123.5555
var roundedNumber = (Math.floor(value * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)
```

roundedNumber will be "123.55" as a string. So if you want as a number just add:

```
var value = 123.5555
var roundedNumber = Number((Math.floor(value * 100) / 100).toFixed(2))
```

and now you have value as a number and fixed to up 2 decimal places.

Comment: but `+(Math.floor(10230.22 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)` is `10230.21` ‍♂️

Comment: @kanlukasz you need [Number.EPSILON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON): `Math.round((value + Number.EPSILON) * 100)/100`

Answer (score 0):

Just copy paste this method and call this method on your respective button on which button you have to check this decimal validation.

```
function CheckDecimal(inputtxt)   
  {   
  var decimal=  /^[-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/;   
  if(inputtxt.value.match(decimal))   
    {   
    alert('Correct, try another...')  
    return true;  
    }  
  else  
    {   
    alert('Wrong...!')  
    return false;  
    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Java script way  :

    (isNaN(value)) <-- First to check the input value is number

    
    After verifying the value input is numeric, check the value should have only two decimal values after this, also allow single value to pass

    function checkDecimal(value)   
    {  
        var split = value.split('.');
        console.log(split);
        if (split.length === 2 && split[1].length > 2) {
            console.log(split[1].length);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```